# CSS position fixed within a div container with a width same as the parent container

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have 3 div, left center and right, I wish to have a div (notification) inside center section and is fixed position so that when scroll, it always stay at that position. And when change the browser size, the notification will still stay inside the center div and change size accordingly. Currently, when I use position: fixed, it is using viewport instead of the center div.

My desired output will be the notification blue bar is the same size relative to the center div with left and right padding and when reducing the size of the browser, the blue bar still stays within the center div.

**Current Display:**
[image: Current Display]
**Expected Display:**
[image: Expected Display]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: red; height: 1000px">Test</div>
  <div class="col-lg-7" style="background-color: yellow; height: 1000px">
  
   <div style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 9999; width: 100%; padding-left: 5; top: 50"><div style="position: fixed; background-color: blue; ">Notification</div></div>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: green; height: 1000px">Test3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As shown here in the snippets preview (once you expand it to full page), it's far more like the expected than 'current' result. (Firefox.)

Answer (score 1):

added below `css` to the notification `div`

```
position: absolute; background-color: blue; height:30px;
      width:100%; top:20px; color: white
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: red; height: 1000px">Test</div>
  <div class="col-lg-7" style="background-color: yellow; height: 1000px">
  
   <div style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 9999; width: 100%; padding-left: 5; top: 50"><div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; height:30px;
      width:100%; top:20px; color: white">Notification</div></div>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>
  Test<br>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: green; height: 1000px">Test3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute replace of fixed. I add

```
position: absolute;top:30px;width: 90%;text-align:center;left:5%;
```

Replace of position: fixed;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: red; height: 1000px">Test</div>
        <div class="col-lg-7" style="background-color: yellow; height: 1000px">

            <div style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 9999; width: 100%; padding-left: 5; top: 50"><div style="position: absolute;top:30px;width: 90%;text-align:center;left:5%; background-color: blue; ">Notification</div></div>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>
        Test<br>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: green; height: 1000px">Test3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Obaidul, thanks alot, but my desire output will be when scroll, the notification bar will be stay visible that is why i chose position: fixed. By using absolute, when scroll, the bar will move which is not the behavior that i wanted.

Comment: Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes but need to use javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Position : sticky, which entirely does the same thing as fixed other than positioning an element based on the user's scroll position.
The only exception being, it is not supported in IE 11.0

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: red; height: 1000px">Test</div>
    <div class="col-lg-7" style="background-color: yellow; height: 1000px">

      <div style="
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding-left: 5;
    top: 50px;">
        <div style="background-color: blue; ">Notification</div>
      </div>
      Test<br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br> Test
      <br>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: green; height: 1000px">Test3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Charu, Thanks for your advice, but if IE11 is not supported, then i think i will not be using this method as i need a solution that support most of the common browser.